# How to change Firefox 4 full screen title bar gradient

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, taskbar, gradient

Is it possible to change this gradient to something else (preferably a solid color or the default gradual horizontal fade)?

[image: titlebar]

Using Firefox 4.0 on Windows-XP-x86-Pro-SP3.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the 'tabs on top' feature. Obviously you will lose that option but you'll get your usual title bar back, making Firefox 4 look a little more like Firefox 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Mozilla focused only on Windows 7 for their slick Firefox 4 UI.
So, people get an additional title bar in older Windows'.

In a nutshell, no it's not possible. =/

Answer (score 0):

I would think it is possible but you would be changing the color of all windows title bars - not just for Firefox. To change title bar colors you right click on the desktop and select properties. You can change the appearance of windows somewhere in there.

Comment: The thing is, no other window behaves this way. This is something special that Firefox does when you maximize it.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with add-ons like [Hide Caption Titlebar Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-caption-titlebar-plus-sma/).

For me it ended up looking like this:

[image: Titlebar screenshot]